# Where to break line?

Tags: spelling

I have a few sentences that I needed translated to Japanese, and found someone to do it for me. However, I have no clue where I can break the sentences on two lines (as some don’t fit in the space I have). I can't ask the person again. Can someone please help?

実験室でテスト済み line break needed near the middle

体の自然な解毒能力を高めましょう line break needed around fifth or sixth character from the end

ナチュラルライフのための天然成分 line break needed near the middle

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are not a translation or proof-reading site.  If you already found someone help you with translation, why aren't you using the same person with this particular request.  It seems to me that they would be the best source for such information.

Answer (score 2):

The first two are straightforward.

> 実験室で
> テスト済み

> 体の自然な解毒能力を
> 高めましょう

The last one becomes a bit awkward if if the line break has to come near the middle, but I would put it this way.

> ナチュラルライフ
> のための天然成分

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.